# Const unsigned char* to char*

Tags: c++, string, types, char

So, I have two types at the moment:

```
const unsigned char* unencrypted_data_char;
string unencrypted_data;
```

I'm attempting to perform a simple conversion of data from one to the other (string -> const unsigned char*)

As a result, I have the following:

```
strcpy((unencrypted_data_char),(unencrypted_data.c_str()));
```

However, I'm receiving the error:

```
error C2664: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const unsigned char *' to 'char *'
```

Any advice? I thought using reinterpret_cast would help, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't write to a const char *, because each char pointed to is *const*.

strcpy *writes* to the first argument. Hence the error.

Don't make `unencrypted_data_char` const, if you plan on writing to it (and make sure you've allocated enough space for it!)

And beware of strcpy's limitations. Make sure you know how big your buffer needs to be in advance, because *strcpy doesn't stop 'til it gets enough* :)

Comment: Unfortunately, its not my choice to make it constant or not. The parameters of the AES encryption function that I'm passing unencrypted_data to require that it is in the form of "const unsigned char", hence my problem.

Comment: BSchlinker, that's not a problem.  `unsigned char*` can be implicitly converted to `const unsigned char*`.

Comment: No, no -- If a function takes something like `void f(const char *)`, it's just saying that *it* won't write to it! It doesn't stop you from giving it a mutable buffer.

Comment: Like Alex said: Avoid using strcpy! Maybe using strncpy is an option.

And: If you are using a mutable buffer for the AES function and then strcpy to copy its contents to another mutable buffer. Why don't you give the latter to the AES function directly?

Answer (score 0):

well if unencrypted_data_char point to a memory that is only readable,you'd better not to write any data on it,it will certainly cause a segment fault.

e.g:

```
    const char *a="abc";
```

a pointed to a readable only memory

if unencrypted_data_char is const only because you let it be(like const char* a=b),well you could use const_cast< char* >(a) to conver it.

if converting from const char* to unsigned char*.

1.you need convert from const char* to char*.use const_cast.

2.conver from char* to unsigned char*. use reinterpret_cast.